# Swift Scenekit Camera: In Direction of Character

Tags: ios, swift, camera, constraints, scenekit

I am trying to create my own game using Swift and I want to know how to use the camera in SceneKit to make it fixed to the back of the characters head and also move and rotate with the camera.

My first idea was to make the direction of the character be equal to the direction of the camera but that didn't work.

My second idea was to use some camera constraints but they didn't seem to work neither. I used the a combination of the lookAtConstraint, replicatorConstraint and distanceConstraint. I was thinking that using the IKConstraint might work but that always gives me an error when I use it.

I have kinda ran out of ideas on what to use so if anyone has any suggestions that will be well appreciated. Thank you!!

Below is the function that sets up the camera:

```
func setupFollowCamera(_ cameraNode: SCNNode) {
    // look at "lookAtTarget"
    let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: self.lookAtTarget)
    lookAtConstraint.influenceFactor = 0.07
    lookAtConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true

    // distance constraints
    let follow = SCNDistanceConstraint(target: self.lookAtTarget)
    let distance = CGFloat(simd_length(cameraNode.simdPosition))
    follow.minimumDistance = distance
    follow.maximumDistance = distance

    // configure a constraint to maintain a constant altitude relative to the character
    let desiredAltitude = abs(cameraNode.simdWorldPosition.y)
    weak var weakSelf = self

    let keepAltitude = SCNTransformConstraint.positionConstraint(inWorldSpace: true, with: {(_ node: SCNNode, _ position: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 in
        guard let strongSelf = weakSelf else { return position }
        var position = float3(position)
        position.y = strongSelf.character!.baseAltitude + Float(0.75)
        return SCNVector3( position )
    })

    // replicator constraint
    let repli = SCNReplicatorConstraint(target: self.lookAtTarget)
    repli.positionOffset = SCNVector3(0, 0, 1)
    repli.replicatesOrientation = true

    //let ik = SCNIKConstraint(chainRootNode: (self.character?.node)!)


    // use a custom constraint to let the user orbit the camera around the character
    let transformNode = SCNNode()
    let orientationUpdateConstraint = SCNTransformConstraint(inWorldSpace: true) { (_ node: SCNNode, _ transform: SCNMatrix4) -> SCNMatrix4 in
        guard let strongSelf = weakSelf else { return transform }
        if strongSelf.activeCamera != node {
            return transform
        }



        let targetPosition = strongSelf.lookAtTarget.presentation.simdWorldPosition
        let cameraDirection = strongSelf.cameraDirection
        //let cameraDirection = strongSelf.characterDirection
        if cameraDirection.allZero() {
            return transform
        }


        let characterWorldUp = strongSelf.character?.node?.presentation.simdWorldUp

        transformNode.transform = transform

        let q = simd_mul(
            simd_quaternion(GameController.CameraOrientationSensitivity * cameraDirection.x, characterWorldUp!),
            simd_quaternion(GameController.CameraOrientationSensitivity * cameraDirection.y, transformNode.simdWorldRight)
        )

        transformNode.simdRotate(by: q, aroundTarget: targetPosition)
        return transformNode.transform
    }

    //cameraNode.constraints = [keepAltitude, orientationUpdateConstraint, lookAtConstraint, follow]
    cameraNode.constraints = [lookAtConstraint, repli]
}
```

Comment: Pls show us what you've done so far like code. Avoid [XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). See [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera)